# Why is this not updating the table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I am using this method to update the table using JTextFiled, but nothing is happening. The code is inside constructor

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    int row = table.getSelectedRow();

    Object value3 = table.getValueAt(row, 3);
    Object value1 = table.getValueAt(row, 1);
    Object value2 = table.getValueAt(row, 2);

    enterText.setText(value3 == null ? null : value3.toString());
    startTime.setText(value1 == null ? null : value1.toString());
    endTime.setText(value2 == null ? null : value2.toString());

    Object getValue3 = enterText.getText();
    if(value3 != getValue3){
     table.setValueAt(getValue3, row, 3);


    }
    }
});
```

The data is showing when I select the row inside the text field but when I change it and send it back to the JTable it is not happening. I think I need a listener.

Comment: " I think I need a listener." okay did you try it?

Comment: whay kind of listener also i need it to be inside the constrictor

Comment: any idea how to use firetablecellupdate

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!value3.equals(getValue3)) { ... }
```

Comment: that is the same thing do you have other way

Comment: It's NOT the same! Yours is testing for the same instance, mine is checking for equality

Comment: And that's why it's a good idea leaving a little comment when posting an answer and explain why your solution is better/will work and what are you doing.

Comment: but this is wrong it show null pointer hint and the wrong are not form the ide